# I add a Firebase Framework without using cocoa pods

Tags: swift, firebase

I am working in Firebase in swift. I add a Firebase Framework without using cocoa pods. I add some Framework but it not working.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow Yaseen! You should have a read of the help articles, specifically, "How to Ask". We need you to provide some more info, for example any errors you are seeing in order to properly assist you.

Answer (score 1):

You can Possibly look into the Following Description

They have explained all the steps in detail: [Steps to integrate Firebase](http://www.mokacoding.com/blog/setting-up-firebase-without-cocoapods/)

Link to the Official Documentation: [Firebase Docs](https://firebase.google.com/docs/ios/setup)

[image]

Possible solution to the problem of missing File :- [Issue Soluiton](https://github.com/invertase/react-native-firebase/issues/153)

Video to the Steps are :- [Video Explaination](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=a34VMARzqLs)

Comment: i already follow this website.but its not working

Comment: Edited the answer to Firebase docs, they have explained the steps with cocoapods and without cocoapods also

Comment: yeah there is read me file in firebase folder but there is some issue when i used it in our app

Comment: i follow this step but not working there is no video in youtube about that.

Comment: Edited with possible solution in it

Comment: *"not working" is not a problem description.* Edit your question to explain **why** it doesn't work.

Comment: @YaseenKhan Edited the Answer with video Solution

Comment: please send me the link of the video

Comment: Has added the link in the answer , pleas find that